# Python: If Statements, Raw_Input and List Gen

Tags: python

I'm having a strange issue taking in user input, appending a list with the correct information, and checking the list for the correct input.

For some reason, only entering 'pally' calls `end_instance.enter()` (without 'polly').

```
def enter(self):
    print """Please enter your two passwords to proceed. Check the other doors for answers. You have five guesses."""

    green_count = 0

    green_ans = []

    while green_count < 5:

        green_guess = (raw_input('> '))

        if 'polly' or 'pally' in green_guess:
            green_ans.append(green_guess)
            green_count += 1

            if 'polly' and 'pally' in green_ans:
                print "cool"
                end_instance.enter()
        else:
            print "try again"
            green_count += 1
```

Comment: `if 'polly' or 'pally' in green_guess:` should be `if 'polly' in green_guess or 'pally' in green_guess:` Similarly for the `and` check

Answer (score 1):

`'polly'` and `'pally'` are both non-empty strings, and thus equate to
`True` in boolean contexts in Python. Using `or` and `and` computes the
boolean expression with short-circuit evaluation:

```
>>> 'polly' or 'pally'
'polly'   # first True value; second not checked
>>> 'polly' and 'pally'
'pally'   # last True value; both checked
```

So, the line:

```
if 'polly' and 'pally' in green_ans:
```

is equivalent to saying:

```
if 'pally' in green_ans:
```

Thus, only `'pally'` works.

Answer (score 0):

`'polly'` will always be true.

Therefore, change your code to this:

```
def enter(self):
    print """Please enter your two passwords to proceed. Check the other doors for answers. You have five guesses."""

    green_count = 0

    green_ans = []

    while green_count  '))

        if 'polly' in green_guess or 'pally' in green_guess:
            green_ans.append(green_guess)
            green_count += 1

            if 'polly' in green_guess and 'pally' in green_guess:
                print "cool"
                end_instance.enter()
        else:
            print "try again"
            green_count += 1
```